# How badly damaged was the Sdf-1?

Tags: robotech

How badly damaged was sdf-1 after the final space Battle? 
And why was the bridge still visible after IT was supposedly completely destroyed in episode to the stars?  The bridge seemed intact in this episode .
Can anybody please explain this?

Answer (score 2):

If by "final" battle, you mean the battle against Khyron in episode 36th "To the Stars", it was destroyed to the point it became garbage and buried. The bridge wasnt intact after that because the SDF-1 was buried and it doesnt appear anymore.

If by "final" battle you mean the battle were it was almost destroyed in episode 27th "Force of Arms", it was damaged enough that they didnt use it anymore until the last episode, when they partially repaired it for it to fly again, they made it fly once last time again against Khyron who finally destroyed it by making his vessel collision with it.

Something of this info you can see it here:
http://robotech.wikia.com/wiki/To_the_Stars